# LinkedList Iteration Exception

Tags: java, exception, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I am struggling with this error. I feel its really simple but cannot understand why am getting the error.

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` when I iterate through values in my linked list.

Code Snippet:

```
private void updateBuyBook(LimitOrder im) {

    LimitOrder lm = null;

    Iterator itr = buyBook.entrySet().iterator();

    boolean modify = false;

    while (itr.hasNext() && !modify) {

        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) itr.next();
        if ((((LinkedList<IMessage>) pairs.getValue()).size() > 0)) {
            LinkedList<ILimitOrder> orders = (LinkedList<ILimitOrder>) pairs
                .getValue();
            ListIterator listIterator = orders.listIterator();
            while (listIterator.hasNext() && !modify) {
                LimitOrder order = (LimitOrder) listIterator.next();

                if (order.getOrderID().equalsIgnoreCase(im.getOrderID())) { // error at this line
                    lm = order;
                    addToBuyMap(im);
                    modify = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (modify = true) {
                orders.remove(lm);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error is at this line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
order.getOrderID().equalsIgnoreCase(im.getOrderID()));
```

Please help. Is my assignment wrong in any way???
Please help!!!
Thanks

Comment: The thing that's unexpectedly null could be order, its order ID, or im. Any of these would cause an NPE at this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your code a bit will make it longer, but much easier to find the error... instead of doing:

```
if (order.getOrderID().equalsIgnoreCase(im.getOrderID())) {
```

Change it to:

```
String orderID = order.getOrderID();
String imOrderID = im.getOrderID();

if(orderID.equals(imOrderID()) {
```

Then you will know if `order` or `im` is null.  If neither of those is null then the things that could be null are `orderID` and `imOrderID`.  It is now a simple matter of finding out which one of those is null.

If it is order or im then the program will crash on the `order.getOrderID()` or `im.getOrderID()` lines.

If, instead it is `orderID` or `imOrderID` that is null, then it will crash on `if(orderID.equals(imOrderID()) {`.  You can then use System.out.println (or something better, like a debugger) do easily find out what is wrong.

If neither of those should be null then I suggest adding something like:

```
if(orderID == null) { throw new IllegalStateException("orderID cannot be null"); }
if(imOrderID == null) { throw new IllegalStateException("imOrderID cannot be null"); }
```

and then track down how it got set to null to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're *passing in* the null, into im. I'll need to see more of the code to be sure.

Comment: you could put System.err.println(im) in there, temporarily, to check.

Comment: when i try printing order.getOrderId() i get null value. There is a lot of code. this isone of the functions. Thanks

Comment: then thats why its throwing NPE. You are doing null.equalsIgnoreCase() which will blow up.

Answer (score 0):

You never check to see if `im` is null. I suspect it is.

Answer (score 0):

One first look, where is `im` instantiated? You can also try to debug in your IDE so as to see whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like im is ever declared / assigned. So

```
im.getOrderID()
```

is probably where the null pointer exception is generated.

-- Dan

Edit:

Missed that im is passed in as an argument. So that leaves a few possibilities (in order of likelihood):

1. im is null (ie. user called function with null parameter)
2. order.getOrderID() is returning null
3. order is null (ie. the list has nulls in it)

Edit2:

Your line

```
if (modify = true)
```

Is fundamentally wrong and will always evaluate to true (single equal is for assignment, == is for comparison.)

When simply checking if a flag boolean is true or false, it is best to use:

```
boolean flag = true;

if(flag)
{
    // True block
}
else
{
   // False block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either im is null or order.getOrderID() is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you could add a debug point before that line and see which variable is null. looking at the code the answer is 1. order is null 2. order.getOrderID() is null or 3. im is null